Said what to do without realizing, should I apologize?
Ok, technical IT meeting about some processes.
At some point I asked if I could have a certain things because this way user could not do that and another thing cannot happen. Never considered the other party could have already handled that in a different way. But I did not expected because I had no knowledge of the system from a certain point on.
This is small company part of a bigger company, and that person is of the other bigger company. Never met in person.
Should I reach out on company messaging app and make a short call to apologize?
I fear that could have been interpreted as "are you stupid?"
Even if it was not my intention, I already had some hard times because when cooperating on projects the other parts did not implemented easy to implement features (in this case this was not easy, but could have avoided a rare problem that could be difficult to detect and potentially harmful to the company, in other cases things like adding a column to a DB would have saved me days of work, but usually I start working on stuff which details are already fixed and immutabile). So since this is my first meeting where I have the chance to do so. I took the chance to ask and immediatly regretted. (Not to mention the potential difference in gender).
While I don't think that thing was so important, there was some silence.
Thanks.

Its unclear exactly why you regret asking this question - if it was about a feature the other company implemented that you had no knowledge of, I don't think you should worry about it. If anything use it as a learning experience to word your questions more carefully so that they can't be interpreted in an offensive way.

The exact problem was about inserting data in a table that should be Daily removed After some ingestion. I asked for a diff table instead of truncation because this way users do not incurr the risk to be inserted After ingestion but before truncation. Didn't realized they could have used a transaction (which of course prevent me insertions and I go in timeout). Is literally a basic problem don't know why I asked that

This would be culturally dependent.  Probably just let it go (I am in US).  If it comes up, apologize and then move on.

No, I do not think you need to apologize. This sounds like a small technical misunderstanding that you are making into a big deal in your head, I doubt that the person on the other end of this transaction even remembers it happening. My advice is to brush it off and make it into a learning experience: when you're in similar situations in the future, take the extra second to ask yourself why a solution that presents itself as intuitive to you was not implemented. If the answer is obvious, then you can avoid asking the unnecessary question. If the answer is not obvious, then it is a reasonable question to ask. This is a great workplace practice in general - cross examine your assumptions before you voice them, this way you can avoid raising non-existent issues and you will likely present yourself as much more thoughtful and intuitive.
